# Where-Object - two "equal" values

Tags: powershell

How can I put two parmeters or values into one "-eq" in Where-Object?

My Code is the following:

```
$Drives | where {$_.Gruppe -eq $env:username} | foreach {
    $_.Gruppe = $UserOU
}

$Drives | where {$_.Gruppe -eq 'Alle'} | foreach {
    $_.Gruppe = $UserOU
}
```

But it doesn't seem logical to me that I need two Scriptblocks for this. Can I put that in one line, like this?

```
$Drives | where {$_.Gruppe -eq ($env:username -or 'Alle')} | foreach {
    $_.Gruppe = $UserOU
}
```

This returns an error - but something like this should be possible, right?

Comment: `? Gruppe -in $env:username,Alle`

Comment: `$Drives | where {$_.Gruppe -eq "$env:username " -or $_.Gruppe -eq 'Alle' }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Powershell version 2 you should do it this way:

```
$Drives | where {$_.Gruppe -eq $env:username -or $_.Gruppe -eq 'Alle'} | foreach {
    $_.Gruppe = $UserOU
}
```

For Powershell version 3 or above you could use **-in** operator like this:

```
$Drives | where {$_.Gruppe -in $env:username,'Alle'} | foreach {
        $_.Gruppe = $UserOU
}
```

Comment: In v2 you have `-contains`: `$env:username,'Alle' -contains $_.Gruppe`.